# Ansible can not locate file in lookup when using a tilde in path

Tags: ansible

Using the `default` directory in Ansible, I set the variable:

```
vm_public_key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

I have a task that use a `Jinja` template, This template will use the `vm_public_key` variable.
 But I have an error:

> "msg": "AnsibleError: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"

To summarize, It can't find the ssh key.
The workaround was to replace the tilde `~` with the home directory `/home/MY_USER`. But I need to replace it with something more flexible, like the tilde.
The command I use to run the ansible :

> sudo ansible-playbook -K playbook.yml -i hosts --connection=local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}` to retrieve the value of `$HOME` which is equal to the tilde.

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed, just need to replace USER by HOME, since I need the home directory path. Thank you

Comment: ah damn, yes. Glad I could help  :)